# How to attach a command to longpress on a command in the Toolbar?

Tags: codenameone

When I add a `Command` X to the `Toolbar`, I would like to be able to attach an additional command Y which is activated on a `longpress` on the icon of the X command.

With Buttons I can achieve this by overriding the `longPointerPress(x,y)`. Is there some approach I can use to do the same for Commands in the Toolbar?

Answer (score 1):

We don't have explicit support for that as part of the standard `Toolbar` abstraction. You can do one of these hacks neither one of which is ideal:

- Use `findCommandComponent(Command)` on the `Toolbar` and replace the `Button` with your subclass of `Button`.
- Use `setTitleComponent` on the toolbar and replace the entire title area with a `Container` that contains your title and the buttons you want there.

The second option is the official API, I can't guarantee that the first option will work.

Comment: Thanks for the hints, very helpful. I wasn't aware of `findCommandComponent(Command)`so I'll probably try the first option and see if it'll work in my use case.

Comment: I tried using `findCommandComponent(Command)` followed by `toolbar.replace` but the old Command stays in place and the underlying code is too complex for me to try to understand what goes on and how to fix it. Your second suggestion of recreating the Titlebar functionality myself also seems like heavy going so I give up. A pity that a useful feature like longPress on buttons is not possible in CN1.